# Get win32.pyd files with pip on linux system

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

is it possible to get both .so and win32.pyd files using pip on a linux system?

The idea is to have only one folder (in PYTHONPATH) containing the windows and linux version of a python package that will used on windows and linux at the same time.

(Only for packages that contains c sources that needs to be compiled on the system. Example: lxml, pycrypto, ...)